# Trouble pulling RSS/XML in C# (Forbidden)

Tags: c#, xml, rss, linq-to-xml

I have a snippet of code that has been working fine up until a week ago, and now it errors out and the exception says 403 Forbidden. I have been reading that maybe adding "DefaultCredentials" may help, but I am not sure how to apply that to my code.

I am trying to pull data from: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/rss.xml

and my code that was working fine is:

```
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(@"http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/rss.xml");

var LoLtitles = from service in xmlFile.Descendants("item")
                select (string)service.Element("title");
var LoLlinks = from service in xmlFile.Descendants("item")
               select (string)service.Element("link");
var LoLdescriptions = from service in xmlFile.Descendants("item")
               select (string)service.Element("description");
var LoLDates = from service in xmlFile.Descendants("item")
               select (string)service.Element("pubDate");

var servicing = LoLdescriptions.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        servicing[i] = Regex.Replace(Server.HtmlDecode(servicing[i]), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
    }

            ViewBag.titles = LoLtitles.ToArray();
            ViewBag.links = LoLlinks.ToArray();
            ViewBag.descriptions = servicing;
            ViewBag.dates = LoLDates.ToArray();
```

But now the XDocument.Load line is getting a forbidden exception. I can still manually go the .xml's url page and see the file/text, so I am not sure why my program is being denied access all of the sudden...

I have browsed around and I am trying to figure out how to do the **[Default Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184199/receiving-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden-message)** approach that people have used for URL/Web requests, however I do not know how to tack that onto XDocument (or an equivalent approach).

Comment: There are plenty of "why my C# request fails while browser can get it fine" questions. I assume you've looked thorough couple already - please consider adding links/details what did not work.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry! I guess my question is how to apply the credentials thing to XDocument, I have searched around but not found a solid answer yet.

Comment: XDocument can load from stream/string/XmlReader - combine that with answer you've linked and it will work. http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+XDocument+stream+load