# 403 when calling API from Azure App Service

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a strange problem. I have a .NET Core App which works fine on local machine and passes unit tests.

Inside the app it basically calls our platform web service:

```
using( WebClient client = new WebClient() )
{
    NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password);
    CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
    credCache.Add(new System.Uri(_baseUrl), "Basic", creds);
    client.Credentials = credCache;

    var url = _baseUrl + "/api/v1/Pricing/Rates";
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");    
    var request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    System.Console.Out.WriteLine(request);      
    var response = client.UploadString(url, request);
    var responseObject = JObject.Parse(response);
    var products = responseObject["PricingProducts"].Children();

    var result = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    foreach( var product in products ) 
    {
        result.Add(product.Value<string>("LoanProgramName"), 
                   product.Value<double>("Rate"));
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I execute this on local machine using dotnet run, everything works fine.  Unit tests work great too.  The logs on the App Service don't tell me much except that I am getting a 403 from the platform web service.

```
ers.RatesController.Get (AlexaRates) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
2018-02-24 06:37:44.418 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action AlexaRates.Controllers.RatesController.Get (AlexaRates) in 201.3483ms
2018-02-24 06:37:44.447 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HLBRA4B41EO8", Request id "0HLBRA4B41EO8:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadBits(WebRequest request, Stream readStream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 chunkSize, Byte[] header, Byte[] footer)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at Rates.RetrieveLatest() in D:\home\site\repository\AlexaRates\Rates.cs:line 50
   at AlexaRates.Controllers.RatesController.Get() in D:\home\site\repository\AlexaRates\Controllers\RatesController.cs:line 22
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Exten
```

Has anyone experienced anything similar?  I see a bunch 403 posts, but they are mostly about people calling a REST API hosted on the service not calling out.

Comment: 403 usually means your resource is throttled or stopped because it reached a quota limit. Please try to scale your app and try it again.

Comment: Are your service endpoints secured by some kind of authorization policy? The 403 response would indicate that you are an authorized user (otherwise you would get 401), but don't have privileges to access the requested endpoint.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks!  I just updated the app service plan to Basic ($50/month) and the result is still the same.  Any other ideas?  The endpoint is accessible from my unit tests.

Comment: I do have credentials on the API, and the code is the same so my assumption is that it sends the reds the same way

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After trying to add headers and doing various other things the end result was the same - I was getting a 403 error on calling out to a web service.

The solution was to convert from a Web App to a VM and deploy the application there using the old school setup.  The application worked there.

Answer (score 1):

The 403 forbidden error usually means   the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

1. According to your error message, it seems that the error happens in Rates class and RatesController class, which you haven’t showed for us. You could set a break point to check the code in these classes by using **remote debugging**.
2. You say  the project is working fine locally, but get error in Azure, so please make sure you have published all your projects and data sources to Azure. Check whether the ‘_baseUrl ‘ is from Azure. And make sure you have started the Azure App Service.
3. There may be other causes of **403 forbidden error**. Such as page cache and logging in of cookie. You could refer to this [article](https://www.lifewire.com/403-forbidden-error-explained-2617989) to learn how to fix the 403 Forbidden Error.

> Cause of 403 Forbidden Errors
>
> 403 errors are almost always caused by issues where you're trying to access something that you don't have access to.

Comment: sorry for the long reply.  The problem is still there.  I still somehow get the 403 and as far as I know the API should return 200 and the data.  The return is also too quick for the server to analyze it.  The deployment is happening via git deploy so I know that what I have there and what I have on my local machine are the same code bases with URLs being the same.

Comment: I noticed  you use the credentials ，do you have  set any  permissions？

Comment: I do have credentials on the API, and the code is the same so my assumption is that it sends the reds the same way.

Comment: What about this article?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184199/receiving-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden-message). The issue may be related with NetworkCredentials class. I hope my answer would be helpful.

Comment: If not ,you could provide code about Rates.RetrieveLatest() and AlexaRates.Controllers.RatesController.Get(). The error message mentioned them. And change the url address like “https://...”.  https is more safe for Azure.

Comment: Thank you Janley.  I will try that today.  The code for that method is largely copied here.

Comment: Mabye just update code in your question. And error message just mentioned the specific line.

Comment: Hi Janley!  Nope, still no solution.   Do you work for Microsoft?  Maybe we can connect directly and walk through this together?

Answer (score 0):

My fix was that I realized that our infrastructure guys added a IP restriction on the azure app. That is why the app was bouncing back with a 403.

I removed the IP restrictions on the "Networking" -> "Access Restrictions" page.

Comment: You are a criminal!